# How to force the locale/language of a specific app?

Tags: applications, localization

I'm looking for the functionality of MoreLocales2 but only applying the changes to certain apps. In this case, I'm trying to force German on TypoClock 0.51 but have the rest of my phone left in English.

Any apps out there that could do this? Or any suggestions for how to accomplish this? Specific advice to get TypoClock to show in German would be good too.

The device is Samsung Galaxy S2, if it helps.

Comment: You may need to request this from the developer, as the app needs to explicitly ship with support for the language(s) you want. I saw several apps already offering to either auto-select the language ("system default"), or let the user force it to some language (usually to English).

Answer (score 2):

[TypoClock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maapiid.typoclock) and [TypoClock Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.art.typoclock) both use the system language as one can see on the app features:

> Multilanguage (widget uses your system language to display day name and month name).

There's no solution for situations like this, as you can only manipulate the application i18n feature if it was developed with such an option.

You can, as mentioned by Izzy on the [comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/how-to-force-the-locale-language-of-a-specific-app#comment34848_16827), email the developer and see if this can be a feature a for future release.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of forcing a certain app to be in different locale / language than your general phone settings!

1. your device need to be rooted
2. install "Xposed framework" from xposed.info
3. within this app, install a module "App Settings"
4. within this module, search for your app
5. change its locale to "english-us"
6. enjoy